# How to Resolve "TCP backlog setting of 511" in Docker Toolbox on Windows?

Tags: windows, redis, warnings, docker-toolbox

I'm facing an issue where I need to set up a Redis server on Windows 8.1 (which is the only operating system available to me for testing). To do this, I installed Docker Toolbox, but when I run the command:

```
docker run --rm -p 6379:6379 redis:7
```

I receive the following error:

```
WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
```

Within the Docker Toolbox, I tried to navigate to /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn, but the folders only exist up to "sys." "sysctl" does not exist in the Docker Toolbox for Windows (or at least I couldn't use it).

Comment: no one? i need help!